# Installation error in Scyther for Windows

Tags: python, wxpython, network-protocols

I was trying to verify a protocol using a protocol verifier tool called Scyther and was trying to install it for my windows. I was following the instructions from this link (https://people.cispa.io/cas.cremers/scyther/install-generic.html). I have python 2.7, graphviz 2.38 and wxpython 4.0.3. However, whenever I run the code (scyther-gui.py), I get the following error message:

**"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".......\scyther-gui.py", line 141, in 
    class MySplashScreen(wx.SplashScreen):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SplashScreen' "**

What can be the possible issue for such error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SplashScreen` widget is no longer in `wx.SplashScreen` in wxPython 4. It is in `wx.adv.SplashScreen`

See the docs for more details:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.SplashScreen.html

You will have to use an older version of wxPython to make that work.

Comment: Hey, can you help me again? Whenever I click on open, I get this error: 'module' object has no attribute 'OPEN'. Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: I have found the possible reason. I have advanced version of wxpython than I need. I have version 4.0.3 while I need 2.6 / 2.7. Can you tell me how to downgrade the version of wxpython?

Comment: You can get older versions on SourceForge - https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/